# Redefine \citet command (two optional arguments case)

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I need to redefine "\citet" command to have its output printed in red. I did:

```latex
\let\oldcitet\citet
\renewcommand*\citet[2][]{{\color{red}\oldcitet[#1]{#2}}}
```

that works for the "one optional argument" case: `\citet[ARG]{label}`.

How can I get the same result for the "two optional argument" case: `\citet[ARG1][ARG2]{label}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to check for any optional argument, if you use the `#1#{` argument to get everything before the `{`:

```
\let\oldcitet\citet
\def\citet#1#{\citetaux{#1}}
\newcommand*\citetaux[2]{{\color{red}\oldcitet#1{#2}}}
```